# Typescript - Require generic type on function without parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Is it possible to require a generic type on a function without parameters?

Example:

```
function myFunc<T>() {
  return {} as T
}

const a = myFunc() // a: unknown
```

I want to make the generic type required, but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Keep in mind that such a function cannot possibly be implemented correctly. Source: https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1205170798282960896

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yeah, this just works because of the casting but doesn't have any type-safety.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunc<T>() {
  return {} as T
}

const a = myFunc<SomeObject>() // a:SomeObject
```

seems to work just fine.

Comment: That can lead to dangerous code tho. `a` will be typed as `string` but will contain a plain object.

Comment: yes this work. Bus as I asked, is it possible to make the generic type being **required**? It's optional, and will infer unknown if no type is provided

Comment: apparently it cant infer the type into to `const a` without you explicitly passing the type you want. check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548987/281474

Comment: I check this answer before... On the answer that you provide the type can only be inferred because of the parameter. I don't want any parameters.

Comment: you can have a default value for `T` but that's obviously not the same as requiring a type..