# Why is it possible to instantiate a generic class without having specified the generic type parameter

Tags: typescript, class, generics, typescript-generics

I do not understand why TypeScript allows to instantiate a generic class without having specified the actual generic type parameter?
In the following example, the class `Foo` has a generic type parameter `T`.
In the line `const foo = new Foo()` it is possible to create a new `foo` object without having to specify the generic type parameter.
`foo` has the type `Foo<unknown>` and `bar` has the type `valueType<unknown>`.

Why is possible and TypeScript does not raise an error?
What use case is this for?
Can TypeScript be forced to demand for a generic type parameter?

```js
type valueType<T> = {
   name: string,
   key: T|null,
};

class Foo<T> {
   private value: valueType<T>;

   public constructor() {
      this.value = {
         name: '',
         key: null,
      };
   }

   public setValue(value: valueType<T>) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public getValue(): valueType<T> {
      return this.value;
   }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const bar = foo.getValue();
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAbghgGwK4QCrggHlQPigXigG8AoKcgOzgFsIAuKAZ2ACcBLCgcwBozyBrCCAaoAPhSQIEvAL4BuEiQDGCOI0ZQAYgHtt2PKXJQw7eMGjxk9WIhTpI%20hX2NIARgjZKoS7RWYskJWBtFgAKAEpiZyNgAAs2RgA6SxQCKKMMyhprAHIc3kyMwWEoCSkCzPlnGUUjMDcPL0YIYAA1WwhQlOtu%20yxcSMNMuITkjrTuhSMa53r3TyhOFvarCIZejH10zJYWpBYKKBGkyeqSGZ8-YCgAM100iggAdy1dCIVL5hsrNLvtRKWbQ67xIQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable option which is recommended in other [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173191/typescript-require-generic-parameter-to-be-provided) is to default to the `never` type. This will undoubtedly cause an issue further down the line as the `never` type can't be used for anything meaningful, so callers of your class will realize they have done something wrong and that they need to pass a type argument to Foo.

```
type valueType<T> = {
   name: string,
   key: T|null,
};

class Foo<T = never> {
   private value: valueType<T>;

   public constructor() {
      this.value = {
         name: '',
         key: null,
      };
   }

   public setValue(value: valueType<T>) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public getValue(): valueType<T> {
      return this.value;
   }
}

const foo = new Foo();
// bar will now have the `never` type, making it unusable
const bar = foo.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand why TypeScript allows to instantiate a generic class without having specified the actual generic type parameter?

In most cases the generic can be inferred from the arguments.  In this case there are no arguments so it must either be explicitly set or it becomes `unknown`.

Say that we modify our constructor so that it takes a `key` of type `T` as the argument.

```
public constructor(key: T) {
```

Now typescript will automatically assign the generic variable for our instance to be the type of the `key` argument that we pass to the constructor.  We don't need to write `new Foo<string>('x')`.  We can just write `new Foo('x')` and get a `Foo<string>`.

> Can TypeScript be forced to demand for a generic type parameter?

I don't think so but I'm not sure on that.  It would be something in your [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) or linter.

If you require that *every* generic function or class require an explicitly stated generic then that would get very annoying very fast.  Type inference is one of the cornerstones of typescript.  You only want to require it in cases where it would be inferred as `unknown`.

You will commonly see generic functions and classes set a default value for the generic which is used when one cannot be inferred.  `unknown` creates problems but `any` will work (it's just not very helpful).  Nothing is assignable to `unknown` but everything is assignable to `any`.  You can set `any` as the default:

```
class Foo<T = any> {
```

Now when you call `new Foo()` you get `Foo<any>`.

Comment: I absolutely understand that TypeScript would infer from the arguments if possible but what if there is nothing to infer from - like in my example. Does it really make sense to use `unknown` instead of informing me, that there is no explicit type parameter and the type cannot be inferred?

Comment: It’s not a crazy idea to have a —noGenericUnknown or —noInferredUnknown setting.  I don’t think such a thing exists currently but I could be wrong.